# How to add a user with setValue from Firebase Reading and writing data in ios

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am a newbie in Swift and I am learning by building a social media application.
I am struck at trying to implement `self.ref.child("users").child(user.uid).setValue(["username": username])` in my code (from https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write).
I have been following the instructions of Kasey Schlaudt and at this point of the tutorial https://youtu.be/GrRggN41VF0?t=619 he tried to add a user with `setValue` as shown in the Firebase documentation I have linked. The errors I get in the line `self.ref.child("users").child(user.uid).setValue(["username": username])` are

> Use of unresolved identifier 'user' and Use of unresolved identifier 'username'.

My code so far (with some little changes from the original code in the video in my `signInPress` function) is

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import SwiftKeychainWrapper

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var UserImageView: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var usernameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordField: UITextField!
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)
    {
        if let _ : Bool =  KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: "uid") != nil
        {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toFeed", sender: nil)
        }
    }
    
    func storeUserData(userID: String)
    {
        //---------------------------problematic line---------------------------
        //from https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write
        //from https://youtu.be/GrRggN41VF0?t=619
        self.ref.child("users").child(user.uid).setValue(["username": username])
        ([
            "username": usernameField.text
        ])
    }
    
    @IBAction func signInPress(_ sender: Any)
    {
        //this way you make sure there is a property inside emailField.text and you have a variable you can easily use
        if let email = emailField.text, let password = passwordField.text
        {
            Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password)
            { (result, error) in
                if error != nil && self.usernameField.text!.isEmpty && self.UserImageView.image != nil
                {
                    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password)
                    { (result, error) in
                        self.storeUserData(userID: (result?.user.uid)!)
                        KeychainWrapper.standard.set((result?.user.uid)!, forKey: "KEY_UID")
                        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toFeed", sender: nil)
                    }
                } else
                {
                    KeychainWrapper.standard.set((result?.user.uid)!, forKey: "KEY_UID")
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toFeed", sender: nil)
                    
                    
                }

            }
       }
    }

}
```

I would very much appreciate any indication as to why the error does not occur for Kasey and what I might need to change to do the same process.
Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

You're actually pretty close, more of a typo issue. See that your storeUserData function is expecting a string called userID? That's what's needed in the line to store that data instead of `user.uid`

```
func storeUserData(userID: String) {
   let username = self.usernameField.text

   self.ref.child("users").child(userID).setValue(["username": username])
                           here  ^^^^^^ userID instead of user.uid
}
```

Comment: The second error I initially had is still there unfortunately, even though the first error disappeared thanks to you! Suggestions regarding how to solve "Use of unresolved identifier 'username" ?

Comment: @Impostor_Syndrom_Incarnated `username` is a variable that you're not defined in the question; hence the error. If you look at my answer, I defined it `let username = self.usernameField.text` so it would not present the same error.

Comment: When I do exactly as you recommended, I had to make sure to modify writing '''(self.ref.child("users") as AnyObject)''' so with the addition of '''as AnyObjects'''. However still get the error "Value of type 'ViewController' has no member 'ref'". Do you know why that might be happening?

Comment: @Impostor_Syndrom_Incarnated In my answer, `self.ref` points to MY firebase. I store that as class var so I dont have to type the whole every time I want to use it. In other words, I have a class var `var ref: DatabaseReference!` and the in the `viewDidLoad` function I populate it `self.ref = Database.database().reference()`. From then on anywhere I want to use Firebase, i can just type `self.ref` instead of `Database.database().reference()`. Also there's not need for this `as AnyObjects` and it's actually going to cause other issues down the road